# Change the length of footnote line?

Tags: footnotes, rules

I want to change the length of footnote line in different pages of a chapter. For example I want the length of footnote line is "4 in" in page 1 and it is "6 in" in page 2.
I used the following codes for page 1:

```
\makeatletter
\def\footnoterule{
  \hrule \@width 0.4 in \kern 3\p@} 
\makeatother
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ. Please also tell us if you use a package such as `fullpage` or `geometry`.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\footnoterule{\kern-3\p@\hrule\@width\ifodd\value{page}4in\else6in\fi\kern2.6\p@}
\makeatother 
\begin{document}
text\footnote{footnote}
\newpage
text\footnote{footnote}
\end{document}
```